# how to transfer data from editText to sveral activities using checkBox

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, checkbox

i have 3 checkbox widgets and one editText and a Button in MainActivity.java . I also have 3 activities FirstActivity.java , SecondActivity.java and ThirdActivity.java . the question is : how do I transfer the data in the editText from the MainActivity.java to any of the other activities. to be more specific... when I check the first box and click the botton I want the data to be transferred to the first activity, and when I check the first and the second boxes it should transfer data to both the first and second activity...

I've been stuck on this for a while, can someone please help me?!

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do after you click on the button.

Do you want to open the activities corresponding to the check marks?
If yes, in case of multiple check marks, do you want to open one activity on top of another?
If you answer to above question is yes, then you should try passing the data in an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("myData","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the FirstActivity, you can retrieve the value by

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    String value = bundle.getString("myData");
}
```

For a custom object you can use the [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or the [Parceable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) class

But if you already have the activity in your stack and you just want to send them data without actually bringing them at the top, you can try the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
You can define an interface, which will be implemented by your three activities and your ui activity can then keep a track of the three activities and send them data as per the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer data from an activity to another one you have an Intent with an extra :

```
Intent secondActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
secondActivity.putExtra("dataKeyName", "dataToBeTransfered");
```

Then to receive this data from the SecondActivity use :

```
Intent inte = getIntent();
String data = inte.getExtras().get("dataKeyName");
```

And to use the CheckBox you only you have to add the initialisation of the intent in a switch statment
Hope it helps !

Comment: I don't want to open the activities i just want the data to be transferred to all three activities (without opening them) and then I'll let the user know that they were successfully transferred using Toast.

Comment: @Tarek-Dev so why you have picked Him answer as right answer , while this is the same as mine answer ?
So in this case you have to use [SheredPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: i am so sorry...  But he kind of understood my situation and he explained more... I appreciate your help very much though !